# PowerShell to map Managed property to Crawled Property

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, managed-property

in SharePoint Online I would like to map an handful of Managed properties (RefinableStringXX) to some Crawled properties by a PowerShell script to be faster than manual configuration but I didn't find any working examples for SPO.

Can this operation be managed by a PowerShell script in SPO or not?

Comment: Try to be a bit more specific. Your question confuses me. Also show your progress so far.

Comment: @Anteino for example: I have a Content Type in SharePoint Online with a column named "DocumentType", I have to map "DocumentType" to "refinableString00" and I do by UI. But it is a slow method, particulary when you have more than one property to map and in case you have to repeat this action on more enviroments (development, test, production). And so I would like to perform this mapping by PowerShell script.

Comment: @Anteino I don't have any progress because all code I've found use commandlet not valid for SPO as **Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty**  ( https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spenterprisesearchmetadatamanagedproperty?view=sharepoint-ps ) valid only for SharePoint Server.

Comment: @EmanueleLacopo, did you get the script to map the properties?